# Among several lists how to identify a pair of numbers together in a same list?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have some lists:

```
N1={2,7,11,12,14,15,17,20,23} 
N2={4,6,9,10,18,19,22,24,25} 
N3={1,3,5,8,11,13,15,16,21} 
N4={5,8,10,14,17,20,21,22,25} 
N5={1,2,3,4,7,9,13,16,23} 
N6={6,8,12,15,17,18,19,20,21} 
N7={2,7,11,12,13,14,16,23,24} 
N8={9,10,11,12,15,18,22,24,25} 
N9={3,4,5,6,9,13,14,19,23} 
N10={1,2,3,7,10,16,19,22,25}
```

Among several lists, how to identify a pair of numbers together in a same list?

For example, the numbers `20` and `21` are together in lists `N4` and `N6`. How to identify these lists?

Comment: Try with `Select`, `Cases` and friends.

Comment: So you want to know in which list 20 and 21 both are presented?

Comment: Try `Pick[listoflist,!FreeQ[#,20|21]&/@listoflist]`, or maybe you can change listoflist in the first argument in Pick to names of lists

Comment: `Select[Symbol["N" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[1, 10], 
 ContainsAll[{20, 21}]]`

Comment: @Kuba I used your comment. I was unaware of the command `ContainsAll`. It is excellent for my need. But a colleague left something similar and score was for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All other introduced symbols starting with N would appear here if `Global` variables weren't cleared. You should definitely store the lists under one list.

```
vars = Names["Global`N*"];
```

> {"N1", "N10", "N2", "N3", "N4", "N5", "N6", "N7", "N8", "N9"}

```
Select[vars, ContainsAll[ToExpression[#], {20, 21}] &]
```

> {"N4", "N6"}

Answer (score 2):

Your question is ill-posed because you don't tell what you mean by "identify" in "How do I identify which lists have the pair of numbers 20 and 21"? That is, you do not tell us what result you expect from the code that the does the identification.

An answer might be as simple as

```
allN = {N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, N6, N7, N8, N9, N10};
Position[allN, {___, 20, 21, ___}]
```

> `{{4}, {6}}`

but perhaps you want something fancier, like

```
Row[{"N", #}] & /@ Flatten[Position[allN, {___, 20, 21, ___}]] // Print
```

> `{N4, N6}`

(I use `Print` here to emphasize that the results are not usable in further computations)

This will give a result that can be used for further computation.

```
ToExpression /@ 
  ("Defer[N" <> ToString[#] <> "]" & /@ Flatten[Position[allN, {___, 20, 21, ___}]])
```

> `{N4, N6}`

For example, you could copy and paste the last result into `ListPlot`.

```
ListPlot[{N4, N6}]
```

[image: plot]

But really, from the way you posed your question, I can't tell which, if any, of the above code examples will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

First you should define your data as lists by index, `data[1],..., data[n]` or 2D matrix table form.

```
Do[Select[data[ntemp],#1==20 && #2==21 &];,{ntemp,1,n}]
```

---

ps: pairs of 20 and 21? I guess that you means 20 and 21 exists at the same time?

Comment: Have you run this code on an example of `data`?

Comment: this wont work. Run it by yourself.